# boost lexical cast string to double

Tags: c++, lexical-cast, atof

I am facing a conversion issue for which I'd like your help. I'm using gcc4 compiler and I am quite restricted to use gcc4.

I want to convert std::string to double.

```
std::string aQuantity = aRate.getQuantity();
std::string aAmount = aRate.getAmount(); 

// aAmount = "22.05"

double dQuantity = boost::lexical_cast<double>(aQuantity);
double dAmount = boost::lexical_cast<double> (aAmount);

// dAmount =  22.050000000000001
```

By the way, I also tried `atof` and I still have the same issue. Is there any way to use `istringstream` with `setprecission(2)` to get the correct value shown by `aAmount`?

Comment: You just have to print it with less precision. It always has the same precision stored.

Comment: The `boost::lexical_cast` function actually uses `std::istringstream` internally to do the parsing/extracting of the value.

Comment: If i do the following, I am getting 22 instead...        `std::stringstream precisionValue;
precisionValue.precision(2);
precisionValue << boost::lexical_cast<double> (aAmount) << std::endl;

double dAmount;
precisionValue >>  dAmount; // Now I get 22`

Comment: `precision` sets the total number of digits outputted. 22.05 is 4 digits so you need to do `precisionValue.precision(4)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the nature of floating point values, 22.050000000000001 is the closest value to 22.05 that can be stored.  The same would occure if you simply tried to store 22.05 in a double and then print it.

You should set the precision on the output stream if you want to print 22.05.  Alternatively you could investigate a rational number library (for example, [Boost.Rational](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/rational/)).  This would be able to store the value 22.05 precisely, unlike a double (or float).